# Codeigniter Routes for filename with extension

Tags: regex, codeigniter, routes

I am using codeigniter and its routes system successfully with some lovely regexp, however I have come unstuck on what should be an easy peasy thing in the system.

I want to include a bunch of search engine related files (for Google webmaster etc.) plus the robots.txt file, all in a controller.

So, I have create the controller and updated the routes file and don't seem to be able to get it working with these files.

Here's a snip from my routes file:

```
$route['robots\.txt|LiveSearchSiteAuth\.xml'] = 'search_controller/files';
```

Within the function I use the URI helper to figure out which content to show.

Now I can't get this to match, which points to my regexp being wrong. I'm sure this is a really obvious one but its late and my caffeine tank is empty :)

Comment: Resolve the issue in the end I had a rewrite condition in my htaccess file to allow the above files to be accesses as files (which is what they originally were).  Removing this has made the system work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was actually in .htaccess file where I had created a rewrite exception to allow the search engine files to be accessed directly rather than routing them through codeigniter.

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|google421b29fc254592e0.html|LiveSearchSiteAuth.xml|content|robots\.txt|favicon.ico)
```

Became

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|content|favicon.ico)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not need to escape the full stop, CodeIgniter does most of the escaping for you.

Here is a working example I use:

`$route['news/rss/all.rss'] = "news/rss";`

Comment: Thanks for taking the time - your comment lead me towards the eventual answer (removing a rewrite condition allowing these files to be accessed directly).