# Unable to set up pagelime with a codeigniter site

Tags: php, codeigniter, content-management-system

I'm trying to setup pagelime to work with a codeigniter site of mine and it looks like I have everything setup because I can view and edit the site in pagelime, but when I publish the page that i've edited, it says successfuly, but if I go to the webpage, it doesn't contain any of the changes that i just made.

I'm guessing it might have to do with the way that codeigniter url's work because when setting up the site, it asks for the url+index page. I tried setting my index page to `http://example.com/index.php/controller/index` but pagelime always adds index.php to your url so it looks like this - `http://example.com/index.php/controller/index/index.php`.

Has anyone setup a codeigniter site on pagelime successfully and can help me with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I have and the way that pagelime works it will not work with a CI framework since as you have found out, pagelime is setup for standard websites. ie: all pages are in the root and subpages follow the link structure so a link to homepage.com/pictures/album1 should be in the root of the ftp then in the pictures folder and to the album1 whereas we know that the pictures "folder" is nothing more than a controller. I hope that I explained that right or that you can decode what i was trying to say there.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure to add extensions to your routes in the .htaccess file:
[Codeigniter Routes for filename with extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904230/codeigniter-routes-for-filename-with-extension)

In Pagelime, you can set each page to have an FTP Publish Target in the page properties screen. Set the target to the URL of your view, and you should be good to go.

Hope that helps!

Comment: So for the snippet that I need to add to my .htaccess file, would that be exactly what the answer has in the link you posted or will I need something else besides index.php, content, and favicon?

Comment: Ok so without the rerouting piece, it only worked for the home page. Can you explain further how to use the routes or .htaccess file to get the extensions?